# Make Material UI grid horizontally scrollable in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I'm working on a reactjs project and I need to display "books" in a row. I'm using Material UI grid system. I succeeded in showing the books on a big screen. However, The "books" overlapse when the screen gets smaller. I'm trying to make the row horizontally scrollable in the `<Paper>` component when the screen gets smaller without the overlapse occuring.

Here is my code with dummy data and [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-wood-bz0c0?file=/src/App.js).

```
<Paper elevation={4} className={classes.root}>
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="h6">
                Most Popular Books Of All Times
            </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} md={2}>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" alt="Test" />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} md={2}>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" alt="Test" />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} md={2}>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" alt="Test" />
            <Typography >
                Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} md={2}>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" alt="Test" />

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Paper>
```

Comment: @Yatrix This didn't work at all. It messed the whole styling.

Comment: @Yatrix only the last picture was rendered completely!!